How can I resolve the error named "callElasticsearch" in APM?
Good morning,
I have all the observability of the company in ElasticSearch using APM and now appears an error named "callElasticSearch" with this message:

How can I manage that not appears this error? I don't know if I should change something about the cluster.
Thanks for all.
